# how to get the contents of a list in a webpage

Tags: list, html

I want to get the content of a list in a webpage from below

http://www.alzgene.org/default.asp

like select gene, there are some genes list, I want to get all the genes from this list, is there any way to do this?
I am not sure I should contact the administrator since it stopped update since april 2011
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know how to run a script in the browser console here is the JS that will give you what you want:

```
var options = document.getElementById('genesDDDiv').getElementsByTagName('option'),
    result = "Options: ";
for(var i = 1; i < options.length; i++) {
    result += options[i].innerHTML.replace(/<(\/)?option>/, options[i]) + ",";
}
console.log(result);
```

Results:
A2M,A2MP,ABCA1,ABCA12,ABCA2,ABCA7,ABCB1,ABCC2,ABCC8,ABCC9,ABCG1,ABCG4,ABCG5,ACAD8,ACAN,ACAT2,ACE,ACF,ACHE,ACO2,ACSL4,ACTA2,ADAM10,ADAM12,ADAM17,ADAM9,ADCYAP1R1,ADORA2A,ADORA2B,ADRA1A,ADRA2A,ADRB1,ADRB2,ADRB3,AGER,AGPAT1,AGT,AHR,AHSG,AKAP8,AKT2,ALB,ALDH18A1,ALDH2,ALOX5,ALOX5AP,ANK3,ANXA8,AP3M1,APBA1,APBB1,APBB1IP,APBB2,APEX1,APH1A,APH1B,APOA1,APOA1BP,APOA2,APOA4,APOA5,APOB,APOBEC1,APOBEC2,APOC1,APOC1P1,APOC2,APOC3,APOC4,APOD,APOE,APOE_e2/3/4,APOM,APP,AR,ARID4A,ARID5B,ARL5B,ARMS2,ARSB,ART3,ATF7,ATP6V0A4,ATXN1,ATXN8OS,AVPR1A,BACE1,BACE2,BAG3,BAT1,BCAM,BCHE,BCL2,BCL3,BCR,BDNF,BICC1,BIN1,BIRC3,BLMH,C10orf112,C12orf41,C1R,C2,C21orf55,C21orf63,C4A,C4B,CACNB2,CALHM1,CALHM2,CALHM3,CAMK1G,CAMK2G,CAND1,CARD8,CASP3,CASP4,CASP6,CASP8,CAST,CAT,CAV1,CAV3,CBLC,CBS,CCDC134,CCL2,CCL3,CCL5,CCL8,CCNT1,CCR2,CCR5,CD14,CD2AP,CD33,CD36,CD40,CDC2,CDK5,CDK5R1,CDKN2A,CDKN2BAS,CDX2,CECR2,CELF2,CETP,CFB,CFH,CH25H,CHAT,CHD4,CHRFAM7A,CHRM1,CHRNA2,CHRNA3,CHRNA4,CHRNA6,CHRNA7,CHRNB2,CHRNB4,CHST3,CLCNKB,CLPTM1,CLU,CNTF,COG2,COL11A1,COL25A1,COMT,COX10,COX15,CPE,CR1,CRH,CRHBP,CRP,CSF1,CSK,CSN1S1,CST3,CTSD,CTSG,CTSS,CXCL1,CXCL10,CXCL12,CYP17A1,CYP19A1,CYP1A1,CYP2C19,CYP2C8,CYP2D6,CYP39A1,CYP46A1,CYP4F3,DAPK1,DBH,DFNB31,DGKB,DHCR24,DKK1,DLD,DLST,DNAJC12,DNM2,DNMBP,DOPEY2,DPYS,DRD3,DRD4,DSC1,DVL1,DYRK1A,EBF3,EBP,ECE1,ECHS1,EFEMP1,EFNA5,EGR2,EIF2AK2,ENPP1,ENPP2,ENTPD7,EPC2,EPHA1,EPHA4,ERCC2,ERCC4,ESR1,ESR2,EXOC3L2,F11R,F13A1,FABP2,FABP4,FADD,FAM113B,FAM63A,FAS,FBP1,FCER1G,FDPS,FGF1,FGL2,FLOT1,FOS,FOXO3,FTSJ3,FYN,GAB2,GAL,GALP,GAPDH,GAPDHS,GBA,GBP2,GC,GCK,GLO1,GLOD4,GLP1R,GMEB1,GMEB2,GNA11,GNB3,GOLM1,GOT1,GPD1,GRB10,GRB14,GRB2,GRB7,GRIN2B,GRIN3A,GRIN3B,GRN,GSK3B,GSTM1,GSTM3,GSTM4,GSTO1,GSTO2,GSTP1,GSTT1,GSTZ1,GYS1,GYS2,HBG2,hCG2039140,HECTD2,HFE,HHEX,HIF1A,HK1,HK2,HLA,HMGCR,HMGCS1,HMGCS2,HMMR,HMOX1,HMOX2,HNF4A,HPCAL1,HPSE2,HSD11B1,HSD11B2,HSPA1A,HSPA1B,HSPA1L,HSPA5,HSPG2,HTR2A,HTR2C,HTR6,ICAM1,IDE,IFFO1,IFNG,IFT74,IGF1,IGF1R,IL10,IL18,IL1A,IL1B,IL1RN,IL33,IL4,IL6,IL8,INPPL1,INS,INSR,IREB2,IRF6,IRS1,KCNJ11,KCNJ6,KCNMA1,KIF11,KIF18B,KLF5,KLK1,KNS2,LAMB1,LCK,LDLR,LHB,LHCGR,LIPA,LIPC,LIPE,LIPF,LMNA,LOC388458,LOC439999,LOC651924,LPA,LPAR5,LPL,LRAT,LRP1,LRP2,LRP3,LRP6,LRP8,LRPAP1,LRRK2,LRRTM3,LSS,LTA,M6PR,MAGI2,MAOA,MAOB,MAPK8IP1,MAPT/STH,MARCH5,MC2R,MCM3AP,MEF2A,MEFV,MICA,MICB,MIF,MINPP1,miRNA-29a/b,MME,MMP1,MMP3,MMP9,MPO,MS4A4A,MS4A4E,MS4A6A,MT-ATP6,MT-ATP8,MT-CO2,MT-CO3,MT-COI,MT-CYB,MT-DLOOP,MT-haplo,MTHFD1,MTHFD1L,MTHFR,MT-L2,MT-NC7,MT-ND1,MT-ND2,MT-ND3,MT-ND4,MT-ND4L,MTND5,MT-ND6,MTP18,MTR,MT-RNR1,MT-RNR2,MT-TG,MT-TH,MT-TI,MT-TK,MT-TQ,MT-TR,MT-TS2,MT-TT,MYH13,MYH8,MYST4,NAT1,NAT2,NCAM2,NCAPD2,NCOA2,NCSTN,NDST2,NDUFA3,NDUFA6,NDUFA8,NDUFB7,NDUFB8,NDUFS1,NDUFS4,NDUFS7,NEDD9,NEURL,NEUROD1,NEUROG3,NFKBIA,NGB,NGF,NGFR,NOS1,NOS2A,NOS3,NOTCH4,NP,NPC1,NPC2,NPY,NQO1,NR1H2,NR3C1,NRG1,NTRK1,NTRK2,NUDT1,NUMB,NXPH1,OAT,OGG1,OLIG2,OLR1,OPRS1,OPTN,OTC,PARP1,PAX4,PCDH11X,PCGF5,PCK1,PCK2,PCSK9,PDCD11,PDE3B,PFKM,PGAM1,PGBD1,PHKG2,PICALM,PIK3R1,PIN1,PITRM1,PKP2P1,PLA2G1B,PLAT,PLAU,PLCE1,PLCG1,PLG,PMVK,PNLIPRP1,PNMT,POMT1,POMT2,PON1,PON2,PON3,POU2F1,PPARA,PPARD,PPARG,PPARGC1A,PPIL2,PPM1H,PPP1CC,PPP1R10,PPP1R3A,PPP1R3C,PPP2R1A,PPP2R2B,PPP3CB,PRDX6,PRG1,PRKAA1,PRKAB2,PRND,PRNP,PRSS11,PRSS7,PRUNE2,PSAP,PSEN1,PSEN2,PSENEN,PSMB7,PSMB9,PTEN,PTENP1,PTGS2,PTPLA,PVRL2,PYY,PZP,RASSF4,RELN,REN,RFC1,RFTN1,RGS4,RGS6,RPS15,RPS6KA2,RTN3,RUNX1,RXRA,RXRB,RXRG,S100B,SAMSN1,SAR1A,SCARB1,SCD,SEC24C,SEL1L,SEMA4D,SEPT3,SERPINA1,SERPINA3,SERPINE1,SERPINF2,SFRP5,SGPL1,SGPP1,SH3PXD2A,SIRT1,SLC11A1,SLC11A2,SLC18A3,SLC2A2,SLC6A3,SLC6A4,SLIT1,SLK,SMAD3,SNCA,SNCAIP,SNCG,SOAT1,SOD2,SORCS1,SORCS2,SORCS3,SORL1,SORT1,SOS1,SOS2,SREBF1,SRP72,SST,STH,SUPV3L1,SYN3,TACR2,TANC2,TANK,TAP1,TAP2,TAPBPL,TARDBP,TBP,TCF2,TCF7L2,TCN1,TCN2,TET1,TF,TFAM,TFCP2,TGFB1,TGM4,THRA,TIMP1,TLL2,TLR4,TM4SF5,TMC5,TMED8,TMEM132C,TMEM63C,TNF,TNFRSF14,TNFRSF1A,TNFRSF1B,TNFRSF4,TNFRSF8,TNK1,TNMD,TOMM40,TP53,TP63,TP73,TPH1,TRAF2,TRAK2,TREM2,TRPC4AP,TSPAN15,TTR,TUBB,UBD,UBE2D1,UBE2I,UBQLN1,UCHL1,UCP2,USF1,USF2,VCL,VCP,VDR,VEGF,VLDLR,VPS26A,VPS35,VR22,WNT8B,WRN,WWC1,XRCC1,YWHAZ,ZAP128,ZNF202,ZNF292,ZWINT

Comment: hi not sure how to run it, is possible you help me run and send a copy of the gene list to me? thanks